# activating and deactivating scripts on an object from a script in that object (beginner troubles)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object with a script that moves it along a path. On the same object is a script that, if activated, sends it back to its start point. The `mover` script is default active and the `home` is by default inactive. I want it so that if I press "2", `mover` deactivates and `home` activates, and if I press "1", the scripts go back to how they were. states 1 & 2 should be exclusive. I have created a script, on the same object, as follows:

```
public class activator : MonoBehaviour
{

bool mover = new bool();
bool home = new bool();

void Start () 
    {
    mover = true;
    home = false;
    }

void Update () 
    {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("1"))
        {
        mover = true;
        home = false;            
        }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("2"))
        {
        mover = false;
        home = true;
        }

    if(mover == true)
        {
        GetComponent<router>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<routeRepairs>().enabled = false;
        }
    else if(home == true)
        {
        GetComponent<router>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<routeRepairs>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

note the actual scripts I'm trying to activate and deactivate from the object are `router` and `routeRepairs`. When I actually run the game in playmode nothing happens after the button presses.
There is a question that stackoverflow is telling me is similar but the solutions given aren't doing anything for me. So, any help with how to get this working would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
one more thing: I hope to add more movement scripts that should be activated and deactivated in the same way, so solutions that only apply to two states (ie moving or home) aren't ideal. probably not important but it just occurred to me that it was worth qualifying..?

Comment: Did you configure your input? The string `"1"` does not inherently refer to the `1` key on your keyboard. Also, booleans are not objects you do not need to call `new bool()`

Answer (score 0):

Are the inputs actually recognized? Put a print inside the input if to see if it actually gets the input. If not, maybe your input is not configured correctly. Or you can try using `KeyCode` instead like:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
```

Also, you don't need the extra booleans or the extra if statements. Just get the scripts in start and then directly enable/disable them

```
router router;
routerRepairs routerRepairs;
void Start () 
{
    router = GetComponent<router>();
    routerRepairs = GetComponent<routerRepairs>();
}

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCde.Alpha1))
    {
         router.enabled = true;
         routerRepairs.enabled = false;           
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCde.Alpha2))
    {
         router.enabled = false;
         routerRepairs.enabled = true;
    }
}
```